# Javascript, Best method for creating object with vars

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am creating an object in a function - am passed 3 vars, 1 is a name, 2 is a name, and 3 is an array.

So right now I create this object like so

```
   createObj(var, var2, var3){
     var temp1 = {};
     var temp2 = {};

     temp2[var2] = var3;
     temp1[var] = temp2;
    }
```

Which creates and object like

```
 {var1 : {var2 : var3 }};
```

So this works just fine (I want the object looking like that), however I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using so many variables to do it? I am using underscore if this makes it easier. It would be cool if there was a much more elegant (and hopefully) simple way to achieve this. I mean, this method works fine for me, however I am trying to improve my javascript skills, and use less code when possible :). Thanks!

Comment: This is totally fine. Only with ES6 will come literals that allow you to do `{[var1]: {[var2]: var3}}`. Of course, if you're seeing yourself doing this thing over and over, you could write a helper function - which you actually are just doing.

Comment: @Bergi there has to be a more elegant way to do this? no?

Comment: @ajmajmajma Not until ES6, because your keys are dynamic.

Comment: I get errors when I try to work with your code: one of your parameters is called `var`. But that’s a keyword already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally fine. Only with ES6 will come literals that allow you to do `{[var1]: {[var2]: var3}}`. Of course, if you're seeing yourself doing this thing over and over, you could write a helper function - which you actually are just doing.

A little more elegant way to write this function might be

```
function createObj(key, val) {
    if (arguments.length > 2)
         val = createObj.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    var temp = {};
    temp[key] = val;
    return temp;
}
```

so that it works with infinitely many [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). But you might as well just do

```
function createObj(key, val) {
    var temp = {};
    temp[key] = val;
    return temp;
}
```

and call it like `createObj(var1, createObj(var2, var3))` which conveys your intentions better. And for only two invocations you don't need a loop / recursion yet.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some tricky way to do this in one line or something, haha. Thanks for the advice! I will mark this as correct.